# how to evaluate expression in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know there is a  `$eval()`  function which give all result of mathematics like `3+4,  5*4+(5+6)`..But I implement one thing on input field when I type any thing like `5k` it convert in thousand on blur event . Now I need to implement all mathematical operations like `(5k +2k)`..Multiply like `(2k*2k)`..

can we display output upto `two` decimal places?

HTML

```
<div ng-controller='cntrl'>
     <input type='text'  ng-model='user' ng-blur="change()"> 
     <input type='text' to-number ng-model='second'>     
</div>
```

the controller code

```
var dict = {
  k: 1000,
  l: 100000
};
$scope.change = function(){
      var regex = /^([-+]?[0-9,]*\.?[0-9]+)([kl])$/;
      var match;
      if(angular.isString($scope.user) && (match = $scope.user.match(regex)) ) {
         $scope.user = match[1].replace(/,/g , "") * dict[match[2]];
         $scope.user = numberFilter($scope.user, 0);
      }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/FalqWJFCqaFyvJ1xMced?p=preview

Comment: cant you replace the k with '000' ?

Comment: i am replacing 5k to 5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible answer (http://plnkr.co/edit/Uvv9zHtsAL44rIrYpsS5?p=preview) :

```
$scope.change = function() {
    var regex = /[0-9,]*\.?[0-9]+[kl]/g;
    var match;
    if (angular.isString($scope.user) && (match = $scope.user.match(regex))) {

      angular.forEach(match, function(m){
        angular.forEach(dict, function(value, key){
          if( m.endsWith(key) ) {
            var intValue = m.replace(key, '') * dict[key];
            $scope.user = $scope.user.replace(m, intValue);
          }  
        })
      })

      $scope.user = $scope.$eval($scope.user);
      $scope.user = numberFilter($scope.user, 0);
    }

  }
```

Comment: @yonn your anwser is correct but there is problem in that user anwser.http://plnkr.co/edit/RG2AL1ylP5i1hRiOkend?p=preview

Comment: I need to add upto to decimal place..which is not display

Comment: in my plunker it works fine ..only addition and subtraction not work